# Google Docs Hyphenation Script

Tags: typescript, documentation, hyphenation

I have an important question:

Is it be possible to implement german or english hyphenation in Google Docs? (Solved in a similar way as in Word or LaTex (Babel hyphenation)?) I`m not good in writing a Google Script in Docs Script editor. But would it be possible for you to give me a suggestion for a Script Code, to make an add-on for hyphenation?

Thank you very much.